# Liferay 7 custom notification

Tags: jsp, liferay-7

I added a custom notification portlet to send notifications to users. However, once I send a notification, functionality in notifications ruins. For instance, when I access the user's notification page, I can see the notification, but when I try to configure notifications I am getting:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name content.Language, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1299)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ResourceBundleUtil.getBundle(ResourceBundleUtil.java:75)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ResourceBundleUtil.getBundle(ResourceBundleUtil.java:69)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.notifications.UserNotificationDefinition.getDescription(UserNotificationDefinition.java:56)
at org.apache.jsp.notifications.configuration_jsp._jspService(configuration_jsp:514)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:399)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:410)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:70)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.ServletContextHelperRegistrationImpl$RestrictPortletServletRequestFilter.doFilter(ServletContextHelperRegistrationImpl.java:447)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
```

And consequently, on Configuration pop-up window: Notifications is temporarily unavailable. 
Also, when I try to approve, reject or access the notification I am getting:

```
javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: processAction method not implemented
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:195)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:392)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:93)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:249)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:529)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:575)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:334)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.processAction(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:189)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doProcessAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:413)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:117)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:94)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:75)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:114)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:314)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:75)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:170)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:568)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:545)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:303)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:172)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.security.sso.ntlm.internal.servlet.filter.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:107)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:336)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:125)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:303)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:269)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:268)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:260)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: javax.portlet.PortletException: processAction method not implemented
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.processAction(GenericPortlet.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:190)
    ... 187 more

Any action I am trying to do in the user's notification portlet, generates errors. I am using the tutorial from this link http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/12/liferay-dockbar-custom-user.html. 
Any help help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is applied on Liferay 6.2. Liferay 7 no more supports user notification. You can check it here at this link..
**https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/portlet-descriptor-to-osgi-service-property-map**

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

right click on project goto liferay --> sdk--> build-lang;
this will remove the first error.
And for removing second error, right click project and create a new liferay portlet, the default view.jsp wont implement processAction(this was the case in my example).
making a new portlet will create another view.jsp in same project under different folder, and than implement the processAction.